# Error on ant retrieve(sf:retrieve requests) INVALID_LOCATOR

Tags: deployment, ant

I am getting this error after sf:retrieve requests status for my ant job to retrieve my metadata.

> Error: {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}INVALID_LOCATOR -
>   INVALID_LOCATOR: Retrieve result has been deleted.. Retrying...

Comment: are you sure your query is valid? the error message seems to indicate it is not.

Comment: yes it is , it sometimes works in my local and sometimes fails but always fails in jenkins server